# intensive computation parts in the sequential code

Tags: parallel-processing, intel

I have written a sequential code of the algorithm. I am going to parallelize it, but I have to determine which parts of the sequential code are worth to be parallelized. How I can find these parts? Are there any tools to do it?

Comment: What language are you using? You will have to find a profiler for your language + system.

Comment: At the very simplest, you can time different segments of your code and see which segment is the longest. Make sure you time the whole program, too, and that the subsection times add up to the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a profiler such as [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/features.html) or [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) (paid) to figure out which parts of the code are consuming most of the CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not specify your programming language or IDE, I will shoot a guess.
Intel Parallel Studio has great tools on this topic. Also Visual Studio IDE has different profiling tools. If you dont want to use any tools..You can profile your functions manually by using QueryPerformance functions for C/C++.